# Binding data to user (firebase)

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

So I have created working user authentication, and a page which contains 3 inputs and a “create user” button.
The data form inputs is pushed to firebase, but I don’t think it is binded to the logged user.

here is code:

```
export class ProfilePage {

  profileData: AngularFireObject<Profile>

  profile = {} as Profile;

  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private afDatabase: AngularFireDatabase,
    public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {

    console.log('ionViewDidLoad ProfilePage');
  }

  createProfile() {
    this.afAuth.authState.take(1).subscribe(auth => {
      this.afDatabase.object(`profile/${auth.uid}`).set(this.profile)
        .then(() => this.navCtrl.setRoot(MainPage));
    })
  }
}
```

the data on firebase looks like this:

[image: fb data]

Comment: Why don't you think the data is binded to the logged user? Are you getting any error?

Comment: I wanted to display user data, and I got whole data from every account

Comment: What is the query that you used to display the user data??

Comment: You should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49520779/edit) your question to include the code you use to get the user data. And if you want to make sure a user cant see other users data you should also include your firebase security rules and update the question.

Answer (score 0):

With your data structure, here is the "standard" javascript code to get the data for the current user:

```
var userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
return firebase.database().ref('/bike-it-app/profile/' + userId).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
   var firstname = snapshot.val().firstname;
   var lastname = snapshot.val().lastname;
   var username = snapshot.val().username;
  // ...
});
```

Note that here we use "once". You could alternatively use "on", depending on your requirements, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events